# module 'gridfs' has no attribute 'get' I am getting this error in python

Tags: python, pymongo

item = db.WineImages.find_one({'id': id})

```
 image = grid_fs.get(item['id'])
```

base64_data = codecs.encode(image.read(), 'base64')

image = base64_data.decode('utf-8')

Comment: Why do you think that the grid_fs module ought to have a function called `get`?

Comment: We need to see the code where you assigned the name `grid_fs`.  You have apparently done something like `grid_fs = gridfs`, when what you need to do is `grid_fs = gridfs.GridFS(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna use object id in GridFs.
fs.get_last_version('_id': (your variable for object id))